# Correct way to use multiple threads in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, synchronization

i'm doing a little download manager with **C#** and **WPF**.

In my logic there is a main thread (for UI), a thread for manage connection and a thread for each download, until a maximum download number i defined with a **semaphore**.

Every time the user want to download something it adds a custom object `DownloadDetails` in a shared queue, the connection thread dequeue it and make another thread do the actual download.

For a single file it works fine, but for multiple files looks like more threads try to download the same file, trying to write the same file on local drive and crashing when writing stream.

Here some snippets of my implementation

in **main** form:

```
private Thread connectionManager;
```

when clickin download i add the new download (they are all correct, i checked it) and start the connection thread only if its not already started:

```
downloadList.Enqueue(newDownload);
if (connectionManager == null || !connectionManager.IsAlive)
{
   connectionManager = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
   {
      ManageDownload();
   });
   connectionManager.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
   connectionManager.IsBackground = true;
   connectionManager.Start();
}
```

the **download manager** thread do this:

```
private void ThreadStartingPoint()
{
    downloadDetails singleDownload = new downloadDetails();
    while (downloadList.TryDequeue(out singleDownload))
    {
        downloadSemaphore.WaitOne();
        Thread singleDownloadThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
        {
            myDownloadClass.Download(singleDownload);
        });
        singleDownloadThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        singleDownloadThread.IsBackground = false;
        singleDownloadThread.Start();
    }
}
```

after completing the download (or canceling, or getting an error), the single thread do a `downloadSemaphore.Release();`

the problems is that the **myDownloadClass.Download** looks to get multiple time the same parameter when starting 2 or more downloads quickly

i have to use delegate because single download threads needs to update UI on main thread

how can i solve this? Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This fragment

```
while (downloadList.TryDequeue(out singleDownload))
{
    downloadSemaphore.WaitOne();
    Thread singleDownloadThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
    {
        myDownloadClass.Download(singleDownload);
    });

    ...
}
```

is [capturing the loop-variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

The fix:

```
while (downloadList.TryDequeue(out singleDownload))
{
    string localCopy = singleDownload;
    downloadSemaphore.WaitOne();
    Thread singleDownloadThread = new Thread((ThreadStart)delegate
    {
        myDownloadClass.Download(localCopy);
    });

    ...
}
```

As a more general advice, i would use `Task`s and maybe the `Parallel` class to build a downloadmanager.

Comment: are you sure? debugging it i always have a different value because the "TryDequeue" actually remove the value from the queue.. and this loop is done by a single thread so it can't be done multiple times in the same moment

Comment: Try it with the localCopy fix. It fits the _looks like more threads try to download the same file_ symptom.

Comment: tried.. and.. working! thank you :) but i still don't understand why it works, how can this happen?

Comment: The anonymous method that you feed to singleDownloadThread is doing the capturing. I've added a link.